# Getting undefined values from Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a property value of a Javascript object.

My code goes like this:

```
for (key in map.regions) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(states);
    console.log(states.key);
}
```

The variable key will be something like, `"US-VA"`

The variable states should look something like this:

```
Object {US-VA: Object, US-PA: Object, US-TN: Object, US-ID: Object, US-NV: Object…}
```

(This is from Chrome).

However whenever I use console.log on states.key - which should get the object that the key represents, I instead get undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the values from the states variable that correspond with the value in key?

Answer (score 5):

If your browser console log is showing that `states` is defined like you say, use `states[key]` instead of `states.key`.

`states.key` will find the property with the literal key "key".

`states[key]` will find the property with the key that has the value of the variable `key`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Bracket notation here to get value by key

```
console.log(states[key]);
```

and why you need to do this check here [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)